# dropdown menu changing page

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to add a small image, as well as some details, when the user selects a store on the home page. but I can't seem to work out just how the details get selected at same time and then populate the area on the main page.

here's the html.

```
    <div class="storeDetails">
                    <select id="storeDropdown" onchange=>
                      <option value="locationOne"><div class="buttonItem">Sandusky</div></option>
                      <option value="locationTwo">><div class="buttonItem">Bad Axe</div></option>
                      <option value="locationThree">><div class="buttonItem">Imlay City</div></option>
                      <option value="locationFour">><div class="buttonItem">Port Huron</div></option>
                  </select>
                    <div class="storeInformation">
                        <div class="location">
                          <label class="locationDetails"></label>
                        </div>
```

and this is the JS. - I haven't finished the array for the info, because I wanted to make sure 1 worked, if 1 works copy for all 3.

```
// the array of images    
    var images=["./images/bad_axe.gif", "./images/sandusky.gif", "./images/port_huron.gif", "./images/imlay_city.gif"] 

 //this first part is functional i can get a store image to be selected when the dropdownmenu item has been selected. 

    function storeSelect(selectedStore){
    var storeImage = document.getElementById('miniStorepicture')
    var storeInformation = document.getElementById("storeInformation");
        if(this.value == "locationOne"){
          storeImage.src=images[0];
        storeInformation.innerHTML=information[0];
        }
        else if(this.value == "locationTwo"){
          storeImage.src=images[1];
          storeInformation.innerHTML=information[1];
        }
        else if(this.value == "locationThree"){
          storeImage.src=images[2];
          storeInformation.innerHTML=information[2];
        }
        else {storeImage.src=images[3];
          storeInformation.innerHTML=information[3];
        }
        }

    window.onload=function(){
      var selectedStore = document.getElementById("storeDropdown");
      selectedStore.onchange=storeSelect;

    }
// this is the first store details, there's 3 more, I just haven't added all 3 in here. I can't get this to populate, and for some reason it renders the top picture javascript part, non-functional where it was before.
```

the details are in a div called location. div class="location"

```
    var storeInfo=["Bad Axe 707 N Van Dyke Rd Bad Axe MI 48413 P:989-269-9251 or 800-566-3565 F: 989-269-9821, "]

    function storeLocation(selectedStore){
    var storeAddress = document.getElementById('locationDetails')
    var location = document.getElementById("location");
        if(this.value == "locationOne"){
          storeAddress.label=storeInfo[0];
        location.innerHTML=storeIinfo[0];
        }
        else if(this.value == "locationTwo"){
          storeAddress.src=storeInfo[1];
          location.innerHTML=information[1];
        }
        else if(this.value == "locationThree"){
          storeAddress.src=storeInfo[2];
          location.innerHTML=information[2];
        }
        else {storeAddress.src=storeInfo[3];
          location.innerHTML=information[3];
        }
        }
   // so here is the function to write to the screen

    window.onload=function(){
      var selectedStore = document.getElementById("storeDropdown");
      selectedStore.onchange=storeLocation;
      console.log(storeInfo);

    }
```

so the idea, is from the drop down menu, after the item is selected, both the image and the details populate 2 different areas (divs) side by side. 
    why does this thing keep flagging me, with not enough details.

its really simple in my head, create a drop down menu for 4 stores, user selects one, on the one choice, an image pops in div1, and details pop into div 2. why does it keep asking me for more darn details, its annoying. 
    Any ideas? thanks :)

Comment: FYI: option can contain text content only, you can not put other elements like a div in there, that is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```js
function validate() {

  var y = document.getElementById("dropdown");
  var x = y.options[y.selectedIndex].value;

  if (x == 0) {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Default text";
    document.getElementById("image").src = "default.jpg";
  }

  if (x == 1) {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "This is the caption for picture 1";
    document.getElementById("image").src = "picture1.jpg";
  }

  if (x == 2) {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "This is the caption for picture 2";
    document.getElementById("image").src = "picture2.jpg";
  }

  if (x == 3) {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "This is the caption for picture 3";
    document.getElementById("image").src = "picture3.jpg";
  }

}
```

```html
<center>
  <select id="dropdown">
    <option value="0">- Select -</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
  <button onClick="validate()" class="button big">Update</button>
  <br />
  <br />
  <td><img src="" id="image"></img>
  </td>
  <br />
  <p id="text">Default text.</p>
</center>
```